# Init a sessionScope variable every time an JSP app runs

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I really to init a sessionScope variable when an app runs. Which is the right way to do this ?

// Edit: Firstly, I want to sorry for my not understandable question. All what I want is : An listener or something like that which can listen when the app runs first time and create session and put an attribute to it.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "every time it runs"? If you mean "for every single request", then you can use request scope instead of session scope.

Comment: I mean when it runs, not every time. Sorry for mistake

Comment: Question is meaningless. Session scoped variables are initialized with the session, by definition.

Comment: I really want to sorry for my hard-to-understand question, and waste your time. So I edit my question and I hope it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a [`HttpSessionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html).

```
@WebListener
public class SessionConfigureListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        event.getSession().setAttribute("foo", new Foo());
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        // NOOP.
    }

}
```

That's it. If you're still not on Servlet 3.0 (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc) yet, then you need to register it as `<listener>` in `web.xml` instead of using `@WebListener` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

> I really to init a sessionScope variable for my app every time it runs.

sessionScope is created for a session so when your app runs session is not created.

You probably want the application scope for it.

or if you want each time a request is made you want to process the session scope you can do it using `Filter`

Answer (score 0):

Use jsp:useBean tag [spec](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm14.html)

If you set class attribute then if not bean is present in session scope it would be created (default constructor must present)